# How to register custom method interceptor in a Spring Boot test?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-test, method-interception

I am currently migrating a project to Spring Boot and I have a custom method interceptor, which is used in some methods. However, when running the unit tests for the project, the custom interceptor is not being called. I am not sure if I should register the custom interceptor in some way in the tests or create a custom configuration in order for this interceptor to be called.

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class CustomInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor {
        //custom logic
}
```

```
   @CustomInterceptor
    public Car getCar(final Car car) throws Exception {
    //custom logic
}
```

While when I run the application itself the interceptor is working correct, it is not working in test environment.
I have a configuration which is registering my interceptor as a bean in the following way

```
   @Bean
    public Advisor transactionalAdvisor() {
        AspectJExpressionPointcut pointcut = new AspectJExpressionPointcut();
        pointcut.setExpression("@annotation(com.api.interceptor.CustomInterceptor)");
        return new DefaultPointcutAdvisor(pointcut, customInterceptor);
    }
```